# String manipulation - Wrap every word in quotation marks except squared brackets

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a string in JavaScript and wrap every word inside in quotation marks. Each of the words in teh string is separated by "."
The structure and the number of words in the string can vary and appear in following variations like:
'abc.cde.fgi' or 'abc.cde.fgi[0]', 'abc.cde[0].fgi.xyz', 'abc.cde[1].fgi.xyz' and so on.

The result of the conversion should be:

'abc.cde.fgi' -> '**"abc"."cde"."fgi"**'

'abc.cde.fgi[0]' -> '**"abc"."cde"."fgi"[0]**'

'abc.cde[1].fgi.xyz' -> '**"abc"."cde"[1]."fgi"."xyz"**'

is there an elegant way to realize this with regexp for example, or only doing the conversion in some steps using split function and concat the string parts together?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like a trivial task: [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with condition, [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). Have you tried to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace runs of letters ([a-z]) with the capture surrounded by quotes. By adding the global flag, it will replace multiple instances of runs found.

```
str.replace(/([a-z]+)/g, '"$1"')
```

Example:

```js
function quoteWords(str) {
  return str.replace(/([a-z]+)/g, '"$1"');
}

console.log(quoteWords('abc.cde.fgi'));
console.log(quoteWords('abc.cde.fgi[0]'));
console.log(quoteWords('abc.cde[1].fgi.xyz'));
```

Comment: Thanks KevBot! I wasn't aware that JS has such flexible string replacement. Exactly what I wanted - lean and elegant.